# MVC from scratch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't use the ready made MVC template by VS10, I create an empty web application then create folders: Models, Views, Controllers and would like to create a simple MVC web application from scratch, I don't find any tutorial about this online, I have created the DB for my application, I need what next steps I should do to make a login/logout sessioned web application runnable on the browser.

Comment: If you don't want to use the default authentication models/views/controller, Then use it as a template.

Answer (score 4):

Phil Haack has a really empty MVC project template http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/11/a-really-empty-asp-net-mvc-3-project-template.aspx. The bare minimum.

As for authentication why can't you use the default project template which has a working example. If you really don't want to use it, search online. Lots of examples of how to implement authentication. If you have a specific problem with authentication, ask another question here.

Answer (score 0):

The really empty MVC project template is a good start. I'd nuget the jquery, jquery.validation also.

About authentication , I'll give you some hints to research: FormsAuthenticationTicket, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt/Decrypt, Response.Cookies, FormsAuthentication.SignOut (sic), asp.net pipeline events